# Javascript: Is there anything I can do on my end to stop a 403 from occurring?

Tags: javascript, git, asynchronous, axios

im on javascript and im currently trying to work with pull requests, issues and commits from a repo. I have the following code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
var gitPullApiLink = "https://api.github.com/repos/elixir-lang/elixir/pulls";
var listOfCommits = [];
var listOfSHAs = [];
var mapOfInfoObjects = new Map();
var mapPullRequestNumberToCommits = new Map();
var mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects = new Map();
var listOfPrObjects = [];
var setOfFileObjects = new Set();
var listOfNumbersOfTargetedIssues = [];
var mapPRnumberToCloseOpenDateObjects = new Map();

class PullRequestParser {

async getListOfPullRequests(pullrequestLink) {
    const message = await axios.get(pullrequestLink);
    //console.log(message);
    listOfPrObjects = message['data'];
}

async getCommitsForEachPullRequestAndPRinformation() {
    var listOfPrNumbers = [];
    var k;
    // this loop will just make a list of Pull Request Numbers
    for (k = 0; k < listOfPrObjects.length; k++){
        var currPrNumber = listOfPrObjects[k]['number'];
        listOfPrNumbers.push(currPrNumber);
    }
    // I created a separate list just because... I did it this way because on the github API website it seems
    // like the pull request has the same number as the issue it affects. I explain how you can see this down below
    listOfNumbersOfTargetedIssues = listOfPrNumbers;
    // next loop will make objects that contain information about each pull request.
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < listOfPrNumbers; n++){
        var ApiLinkForEachPullRequest = gitPullApiLink + "/" + listOfPrNumbers[n];
        const mes = await axios.get(ApiLinkForEachPullRequest);
        var temp = {OpeningDate: mes['data']['created_at'],
            ClosingDate: mes['data']['closed_at'],
            IssueLink: mes['data']['_links']['issue']['href']};
        //mapPRnumberToCloseOpenDateObjects will be a map where the key is the pull request number and the value
        // is the object that stores the open date, close date, and issue link for that pull request. The reason
        // why I said I think the pull request number is the same as the number of the issue it affects is because
        // if you take any object from the map, say you do mapPRnumberToCloseOpenDateObjects.get(10). You'll
        // get an object with a pull request number 10. Now if you take this object and look at it's "IssueLink"
        // field, the very last part of the link will have the number 10, and if you look at the github API
        // it says for a single issue, you do: /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:issue_number <---- As you can see,
        // the IssueLink field will have this structure and in place of the issue_number, the field will be 10
        // for our example object.
        mapPRnumberToCloseOpenDateObjects.set(listOfPrNumbers[n], temp);
    }
    //up to this point, we have the pull request numbers. we will now start getting the commits associated with
    //each pull request
    var j;
    for (j = 0; j < listOfPrNumbers.length; j++){
        var currentApiLink = "https://api.github.com/repos/elixir-lang/elixir/pulls/" + listOfPrNumbers[j] + "/commits";
        const res = await axios.get(currentApiLink);
        //here we map a single pull request to the information containing the commits. I'll just warn you in
        // advance: there's another object called mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects. THIS MAP IS DIFFERENT! I know it's
        // subtle, but I hope the language can make the distinction: mapPullRequestNumberToCommits will just
        // map a pull request number to some data about the commits it's linked to. In contrast,
        // mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects will be the map that actually maps pull request numbers to objects
        // containing information about the commits a pull request is associated with!
        mapPullRequestNumberToCommits.set(listOfPrNumbers[j], res['data']);
    }
    // console.log("hewoihoiewa");
}

async createCommitObjects(){
    var x;
    // the initial loop using x will loop over all pull requests and get the associated commits
    for (x = 0; x < listOfPrObjects.length; x++){
        //here we will get the commits
        var currCommitObjects = mapPullRequestNumberToCommits.get(listOfPrObjects[x]['number']);
        //console.log('dhsiu');
        // the loop using y will iterate over all commits that we get from a single pull request
        var y;
        for (y = 0; y < currCommitObjects.length; y++){

            var currentSHA = currCommitObjects[y]['sha'];
            listOfSHAs.push(currentSHA);
            var currApiLink = "https://api.github.com/repos/elixir-lang/elixir/commits/" + currentSHA;
            const response = await axios.get(currApiLink);
            //console.log("up to here");
            // here we start extracting some information from a single commit
            var currentAuthorName = response['data']['commit']['committer']['name'];
            var currentDate = response['data']['commit']['committer']['date'];
            var currentFiles = response['data']['files'];
            // this loop will iterate over all changed files for a single commit. Remember, every commit has a list
            // of changed files, so this loop will iterate over all those files, get the necessary information
            // from those files.
            var z;
            // we create this temporary list of file objects because for every file, we want to make an object
            // that will store the necessary information for that one file. after we store all the objects for
            // each file, we will add this list of file objects as a field for our bigger commit object (see down below)
            var tempListOfFileObjects = [];
            for (z = 0; z < currentFiles.length; z++){
                var fileInConsideration = currentFiles[z];
                var nameOfFile = fileInConsideration['filename'];
                var numberOfAdditions = fileInConsideration['additions'];
                var numberOfDeletions = fileInConsideration['deletions'];
                var totalNumberOfChangesToFile = fileInConsideration['changes'];
                //console.log("with file");
                var tempFileObject = {fileName: nameOfFile, totalAdditions: numberOfAdditions,
                    totalDeletions: numberOfDeletions, numberOfChanges: totalNumberOfChangesToFile};
                // we add the same file objects to both a temporary, local list and a global set. Don't be tripped
                // up by this; they're doing the same thing!
                setOfFileObjects.add(tempFileObject);
                tempListOfFileObjects.push(tempFileObject);
            }
            // here we make an object that stores information for a single commit. sha, authorName, date are single
            // values, but files will be a list of file objects and these file objects will store further information
            // for each file.
            var tempObj = {sha: currentSHA, authorName: currentAuthorName, date: currentDate, files: tempListOfFileObjects};
            var currPrNumber = listOfPrObjects[x]['number'];

            console.log(currPrNumber);
            // here we will make a single pull request number to an object that will contain all the information for
            // every single commit associated with that pull request. So for every pull request, it will map to a list
            // of objects where each object stores information about a commit associated with the pull request.
            mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects.set(currPrNumber, tempObj);
        }
    }
    return mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects;
}

startParsingPullRequests() {
    this.getListOfPullRequests(gitPullApiLink  + "?state=all").then(() => {
        this.getCommitsForEachPullRequestAndPRinformation().then(() => {
            this.createCommitObjects().then((response) => {
                console.log("functions were successful");
                return mapPRNumbersToCommitObjects;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("printing first error");
               // console.log(error);
            })
        }).catch((error2) => {
            console.log("printing the second error");
            console.log(error2);
        })
    }).catch((error3) => {
        console.log("printing the third error");
       // console.log(error3);
    });
}

//adding some getter methods so they can be used to work with whatever information people may need.
//I start all of them with the this.startParsingPullRequests() method because by calling that method it gets all
// the information for the global variables.

async getSetOfFileObjects(){
    var dummyMap = this.startParsingPullRequests();
    return setOfFileObjects;
}

async OpenCloseDateObjects(){
    var dummyMap = this.startParsingPullRequests();
    return mapPRnumberToCloseOpenDateObjects;
}

async getNumbersOfTargetedIssues(){
    var dummyMap = this.startParsingPullRequests();
    return listOfNumbersOfTargetedIssues;
}
```

}

I then try to play around and run the function to make sure all the data I need is there by doing:

```
var dummy = new PullRequestParser();
var dummyMap = dummy.startParsingPullRequests();
```

And when I run it on webstorm using:

```
node PullRequestParser.js
```

It will print out some pull request numbers, then stop about halfway with a 403 error. I know what the 403 error is, but I'm wondering if there's anything on my end to stop it from happening, or is it just a matter of working with another repo that won't throw me this error. Thanks!

Comment: The server makes the 403 decision, so probably no, you can't do anything other than handle the error.

Comment: So I guess it's just a matter of choosing a different repo to work with... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error from the server means that your access is forbidden.  You either need to use different credentials (that is, log in as a user with that access), not use that repository, or gracefully handle the error and do something else.  Retrying will not be effective, since GitHub wouldn't be very secure if it just let you have access to things you weren't supposed to.

Comment: I did that and managed to get it working. Thanks a ton mate! :)